# It gives this error while running: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativr.default.createElement')

Tags: react-native

This section of code is not running it always return en error saying undefined or not a function in the render `function()`.

---

### Heading

```
'use strict';
import React, {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight,
    AlertIOS,
    Dimensions,
    BackHandler,
    PropTypes,
    Component,
} from 'react-native';

import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom- 
components';

var _navigator;
//var Navipanel=require('./App/Navigation/Navipanel.js');
var Dashboard= require('./App/Dashboard/dashboard.js');
//var Sample= require('./App/Navigation/sample.js');
var Matches = require('./App/Components/Matches.js');
var Users = require('./App/Components/Users.js');
var SCREEN_WIDTH =require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
var BaseConfig=NavigationExperimental.Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;

var CustomLeftToRightGesture = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig.gestures.pop, 
    {
        snapVelocity: 8,
        edgeHitWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH,
    });

BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
     if (_navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length === 1) {
         return false;
     }

     _navigator.pop();
     return true;
});

var CustomSceneConfig = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig, {
    // A very tighly wound spring will make this transition fast
    springTension: 100,
    springFriction: 1,
    // Use our custom gesture defined above
    gestures: {
        pop: CustomLeftToRightGesture,
    }
});

//var createReactElement = require('create-react-element');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var test = createReactClass({
    _renderScene(route,navigator) {
        _navigator = navigator;

        if (route.id === 1) {
            return <Dashboard navigator={navigator}/>;
        }
        else if(route.id === 2) {
            return <Sample navigator={navigator} /> ;
        }
        else if(route.id === 3) {
            return <Navipanel navigator={navigator} /> ;
        }
        else if(route.id === 4){
            return <Matches navigator={navigator} /> ;
        }
        else if(route.id === 5) {
            return <Users navigator={navigator} />
        }
    },

    _configureScene(route) {
        return CustomSceneConfig;
    },

    render:function() {
        return (
            <NavigationExperimental.Navigator  [//error in this line]
            initialRoute = {{id:1}}
            renderScene = {this._renderScene}
            configureScene = {this._configureScene} />
        );
    }
});
```

Undefined error _reactNative.default.createElement

[image]

Comment: What about `render(){...}` instead of `render:function(){...}`

Comment: I tried that also but same error....

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `<NavigationExperimental.Navigator/>` in a View?

Comment: I tried just now but nothing has changed still getting same error

Answer (score 29):

You imported React from "react-native";

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  AlertIOS,
  Dimensions,
  BackHandler,
  PropTypes,
  Component,
} from 'react-native';
```

instead of this, you need to import React from "react";

```
import React from 'react';
```

When we use JSX in our render functions, in the background JSX runs `React.createElement(...)`. And in your code, React is not defined. Because of this, it gives that error.

Comment: done but still same error, and it is saying: this error is located at=>in test,RCTView,etc

Comment: It seems like a stupid mistake but it happened to me today. 2 hours wasted. Thanks ;)

Comment: It is a stupid auto-complete and lack of focus error I got, lost many hours and saw your solution. Thanks a lot!